# Authentication using certificates

Tags: java, authentication, plsql, cryptography, certificate

I searched about what authentication using certificates means, but I want to find out some specific steps for having 'something' to start working on my project doing this type of authentication. Could you help me? Thanks

UPDATE
Could you help me with suggestions about how authentication using certificates can be implemented?

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I have no clue about what you want / need.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Get a book? Find a tutorial? (Questions for both are not allowed here on SO) Then if you get stuck, don't understand something etc, get back here with a question we can help with. Preferable with code.

Comment: Lookup books with topic Public Key Infrastructure (PKI).